# Some clarification needed in the struct pointers

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

I have a doubt in the following code,

i have a function as follows,

```
void deleteNode(struct myList ** root)
{
  struct myList *temp;
  temp = *root;
  ...//some conditions here
  *root = *root->link;   //this line gives an error
  *root = temp->link;    //this doesnt give any error
 }
```

so what is the difference between the two lines, for me it looks the same..
The error is,

```
error #2112: Left operand of '->' has incompatible type 'struct myList * *'
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What good C programming book have you read? It seems that you don't grasp very well the notion of pointer, and explaining it here would take too much time and space. Read first carefully a good C programming book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that the "->" operator is binding more tightly than the "*" operator. So your first statement:

```
// what you have written
*root->link;
```

is evaluating to:

```
// what you're getting - bad
*(root->link);
```

rather than:

```
// what you want - good
(*root)->link;
```

Since root is a pointer to a pointer, the -> operator doesn't make any sense on it, hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks :)  realized as soon as i posted :)